How to simplify 3D tensor slicing
I want to slice a 3D tensor in PyTorch. The shape of the 3D tensor src_tensor is (batch, max_len, hidden_dim), and I have a 1D index vector indices with the shape (batch,). I want to slice along the second dimension of src_tensor. I can achieve this functionality with the following codes:
import torch
nums = 30
l = [i for i in range(nums)]
src_tensor = torch.Tensor(l).reshape((3,5,2))
indices = [1,2,3]
slice_tensor = torch.zeros((3,2,2)) 
for i in range(3):
    p1,p2 = indices[i],indices[i]+1
    slice_tensor[i,:,:]=src_tensor[i,[p1,p2],:]
print(src_tensor)
print(indices)
print(slice_tensor)
"""
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  7.],
         [ 8.,  9.]],

        [[10., 11.],
         [12., 13.],
         [14., 15.],
         [16., 17.],
         [18., 19.]],

        [[20., 21.],
         [22., 23.],
         [24., 25.],
         [26., 27.],
         [28., 29.]]])
[1, 2, 3]
tensor([[[ 2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.]],

        [[14., 15.],
         [16., 17.]],

        [[26., 27.],
         [28., 29.]]])
"""

My question is whether the above code can be simplified, for example, by eliminating the for loop.

Since your indexing along the second dimension depends on the batch index, I think you need to leverage some weird more complex indexing schemes :
import torch
# arbitrary source tensor
src_tensor = torch.Tensor(range(30)).view((3,5,2))
B, N, D = src_tensor.shape
# arbitrary, non consecutive indices made into an index tensor for torch.gather
ids = [0, 1, 3]
index = torch.tensor(ids)
# slicing
sliced = torch.empty(B, 2, D) #empty instead of zero to avoid writing useless values
sliced[:, 0, :] = src_tensor[range(B), ids]
sliced[:, 1, :] = src_tensor[:,1:,:][range(B), ids]

The  first slicing on the last line serves to offset the tensor by 1 in the second dimension, which makes it possible to access the index+1 values without doing any addition or copying.
Note that if you know for sure that your indices are all consecutives (like in your example), then using narrow instead of slicing will be even better. Alternatively, for some even more complex indexing schemes, you can also try torch.gather
Note : as far as I'm aware, this slicing scheme is consistent with numpy's, so most of the documentation you can find for numpy slicing applies to torch

Thanks for your reply, it helps me a lot

Your approach is highly efficient. On my machine, the performance was enhanced by approximately 8 times compared to for loops. I have another query to pose. Why can't the symbol : be utilized to substitute range(B) during the slicing process? I mean, why are the following statements incorrect sliced[:, 0, :] = src_tensor[:, indices]. Could you recommend some relevant information to me?

@MasterLu I agree, it is confusing but necessary. If you try src_tensor[:, indices] you'll find that the result has shape (B, 3, D) where for each of the B batched matrix, you have extracted the 3 rows corresponding to your 3 indices. But you want something different, where the indexing on the first and second dimensions are iterated together. This is done by indexing the first dimension and second dimensions with arrays of indices that have the same shape (here, shape=(3,)). You can read more here : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

By using the method provided by @trialNerror, slicing performance improved by about 8 times on my machine compared to the for loop.
import torch
import random
import time 
B = 1024
N = 40
D = 512
src_tensor = torch.randn((B,N,D))
indices = [random.randint(0,N-1-1) for _ in range(B)]
t1 = torch.empty((B,2,D))
t2 = torch.empty((B,2,D))
start = time.perf_counter()
t1[:,0,:] = src_tensor[range(B),indices]
t1[:,1,:] = src_tensor[:,1:,:][range(B),indices]
end1 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(B):
    p1,p2 = indices[i],indices[i]+1
    t2[i,:,:]=src_tensor[i,[p1,p2],:]
end2 = time.perf_counter()

print(f't1 == t2 ? :{t1.equal(t2)}')
print(f't1: {end1-start}')
print(f't2: {end2-end1}')
print(f't2/t1: {(end2-end1)/(end1-start)}')

# t1 == t2 ? :True
# t1: 0.002891700016334653
# t2: 0.023338499944657087
# t2/t1: 8.070857908089506

